# Dynamically add small snippets of HTML to DOM - Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a unordered `<ul>` list element that I want to add items to from my Javascript. Just small, simple snippets such as `<li>Label: Text</li>`.

I could use the `ViewContainerRef.createComponent(ItemComponent)` and create a new component for a list item, but I feel that is so overkill when I just want to insert such a simple snippet of HTML to the DOM.

What's the best way to add these type of simple, short HTML snippets to the DOM when it does not require a full component?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need Angular to do this.

```js
function addItem() {
  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += "<li>Item 3</li>";
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
<button onclick="addItem()">Add item</button>
```

Comment: How can I get `document` in Angular?

Comment: @RomanC `document` is a native feature of JavaScript. As far as I know, Angular integrates with JavaScript. Also, the question is tagged JavaScript.

Comment: It doesn't work in typscript, could you create a plunker?

Comment: It's not my problem, but OP's problem, and your answer is wrong that's all.

Comment: @RomanC Quoting from the OP, *I have a unordered <ul> list element that I want to add items to from my Javascript.* Emphasis on the *Javascript*. I don't know why you edited in the tag TypeScript, this question is nothing of the sort.

Comment: What? Angular is written on typescript. I said that's all. I won't answer your replies anymore.

Comment: You're so right. Sometimes when working with Typescript and Angular you get so stuck in that mindset that you forget normal vanilla Javascript. Simple solution is a good one.

Comment: this answer is not correct, the way you described is not angularish

Answer (score 4):

```
myHtml = '<li>Label: Text>/li>
```

```
<div [innerHTML]="myHtml">
```

the added `myHtml` string won't be processed by Angular in any way (no bindings, no components, directives, ...)

See also [angular 2 html binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-2-html-binding/34424375#34424375)